# Android ViewPager - How to bring current page to the top?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager/FragmentPagerAdapter combo with a negative page margin so that the pages slightly overlap each other. Problem is, the center page is not on top. The page to the left of it obscures it. I would like it so that the center page is always displayed on top. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

The z-order of the pages are determined by the order of their creation, so the latter page will be resting on top of the page created earlier (refer first image below).


In normal case, this shouldn't be any problem as the pages are arrange side-by-side with no overlapping region, so the z-order doesn't really matters. However, in the case of multiple visible page with negative margin(overlapping), the selected page might be blocked partially by the page beside it.


One way to overcome this is to keep a reference of the page during instantiation and use it to change it's z-order with `view.bringToFront()`.

[image: view pager instantiation order]
[image: select page blocked view]
[image: reorder z]

To put this in code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private ViewPager vp = null;
    private SparseArray<View> viewCollection = new SparseArray<View>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        vp = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        vp.setPageMargin(-20);
        vp.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        vp.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
                View view = viewCollection.get(pos);  // @@@ Get target page reference
                view.bringToFront();                  // @@@ change z-order to the top
            }
        });
        vp.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            View pageLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.page_layout, container, false);
            final Integer pageId = position;
            TextView pageText = (TextView)pageLayout.findViewById(R.id.page_id);
            pageText.setText(String.valueOf(position));
            pageText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    vp.setCurrentItem(pageId);         // @@@ select the clicked page
                }
            });
            // paint gray shades onto the page background
            pageLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, position*40, position*40, position*40));

            viewCollection.put(position, pageLayout);  // @@@ store the reference
            container.addView(pageLayout);
            return(pageLayout);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 8; // any arbitrary number
        }

        @Override
        public float getPageWidth(int position) {
            return(0.33f);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return (view == obj);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View)object);
            viewCollection.remove(position);          // @@@ remove the reference
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh Bro. You are great. I have trying to implement this bring to front behaviour in viewpager for three days but couldn't get it. You save me. Very very thanks.

Comment: Any idea how you could accomplish the same thing using FragmentPagerAdapter instead of PagerAdapter?

Comment: I follow your code vp.setPageMargin(-20); and save me thank you ^^